# Database driven rule engines in java

Tags: java, rule-engine

I need to develop an application to be able to define the rules through UI and save them to database and need to execute them on some data coming from another source. Is there is a rule engine that supports my requirement? Drools seems to be declarative based but I need to load the execute the rules on the fly. I am new to this rule engine concept. Any suggestions please?

Comment: some answers in this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613/what-rule-engine-should-i-use

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Drools Guvnor](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-guvnor.html)? It lets you save and edit rules, even test rules (which can be persisted on an RDBMS) on the fly, and then integrate (evaluate) them within your Java/JavaEE application. Even if you don't need all its fancy features (such as versioning, IDE integration, etc.) it belies your assumption that Drools can't load rules dynamically from a database.

Note, however, that Drools *wasn't* primarily designed to reason over facts stored in an RDBMS. Starting with Drools 4.0 you can pull in objects from external resources, such as an RDBMS using Hibernate, but if my understanding is correct these will be treated as time-constant facts and not inserted into working memory.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Alistair. I was just wondering, should we always have a drl file for drools to execute the rules or if we have an existing rule schema and the rules defined in db, can we use drools to load them execute the rules, please correct me if I am wrong, thanks a lot...

Comment: Hi Alistair, I think Drools Guvnor comes up with it's own UI to create/edit rules. Is it possible to create a custom UI to instead of using Drools Guvnor web UI, because I wanted to use our application specific UI(look n feel and integrate it into the app). Are there any APIs that let you do it?

Comment: @varaprakash, I am also looking for rule Engine with adding rules over API and integrate with my UI.. Did you find any ?

Comment: I am also looking for java rule engine that can read rules from DB. Do let me know if you have found any?